# When (if ever) is a field extension a tensor product of intermediate extensions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, extension-field

Consider the field extension $K = \mathbb { Q } ( \sqrt { 2 } , \sqrt [ 3 ] { 2 } )$ over $\mathbb { Q }$.

By looking at the intermediate extensions $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2)$ of degree 2 and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt [ 3 ] { 2 })$ of degree 3 and using the fact that $\mathrm{gcd}(2,3) = 1$, one can show using degree and divisibility arguments that $K$ is a $\mathbb{Q}-$vector space of dimension 6 (i.e. $[ \mathbb { Q } ( \sqrt { 2 } , \sqrt [ 3 ] { 2 } ) : \mathbb { Q } ] = 6$).

One can then find bases for the intermediate extensions:
$$
\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2) = \mathrm{span} \{ 1, \sqrt 2\}\\
\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt [ 3 ] { 2 }) = \mathrm{span} \{ 1, \sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{2}^{~2}\}
$$

and thus obtain a basis for $K$ by taking the 6 distinct products of basis elements from above:
$$
\mathbb { Q } ( \sqrt { 2 } , \sqrt [ 3 ] { 2 } ) = \mathrm{span} \left\{ 1 , \sqrt { 2 } , \sqrt [ 3 ] { 2 } , \sqrt [ 3 ] { 2 } ^ { ~2 } , \sqrt { 2 } \sqrt [ 3 ] { 2 } , \sqrt { 2 } \sqrt [ 3 ] { 2 } ^ { ~2 } \right\}
$$

Motivated by the last step of taking all products of basis elements, I am wondering: is it true that
$$
\mathbb { Q } ( \sqrt { 2 } , \sqrt [ 3 ] { 2 } ) = \mathbb { Q } ( \sqrt { 2 }) \otimes_{\mathbb Q} \mathbb { Q } (\sqrt [ 3 ] { 2 } )
$$
where the tensor product is taken in the category of $\mathbb{Q}-$modules?

In cases when there are perhaps more intermediate extensions, are there any criteria for when combining bases in this way will yield the correct basis for the total extension?

(For example, it seems to work here because neither intermediate extension is contained in the other - so do you perhaps need intermediate extensions that only intersect trivially?)

Comment: $KL\cong K\otimes_{\Bbb Q}L$ iff $K$ and $L$ are **linearly disjoint** extensions of $\Bbb Q$. If the degrees of the extensions are coprime, then the extensions are automatically linear disjoint.

Comment: Is "linearly disjoint" equivalent to $K \cap L = \Bbb{Q}$ in this case, or is there more to check? And is this true over base fields other than $\Bbb{Q}$ (e.g. finite fields)?

Comment: There is more to check.... and the base field doesn't matter.

Comment: @D.ZackGarza $\Bbb{Q}$-linearly disjoint means $KL\cong K\otimes_{\Bbb Q}L$ :-) ie. that the minimal polynomials for the elements of $L$ stay the same over $\Bbb{Q}$ or over $K$, ie. $K,L$ are subfields of a common normal extension $N/\Bbb{Q}$ and $K \cap \sigma(L) = \Bbb{Q}$ for every $\sigma \in Gal(N/\Bbb{Q})$